# Pivot Data for XML Export in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, pivot

I have a table in my database that looks like this:

```
@attribute       element       data
--------------------------------------
attribute1       element1      data1
attribute2       element2      data2
```

I want to output XML that looks like this:

```
<element1 attribute="attribute1">data1</element1>
<element2 attribute="attribute2">data2</element2>
```

There are about 30 <strike>attribute</strike> *element* names, sorry, and they're somewhat dynamic. I'm not all that practiced or knowledgeable in SQL. Is there a straightforward solution? Barring that, is there a "best-practice" solution? If I use dynamic SQL, what measures should I take to catch/prevent potential errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doesn't really form a valid xml since you're not specifying a root in your sample output but you can do something like this.

```
SELECT  CAST('<' + element + ' attribute="' + attribute + '">' + data + '</' + element + '>' AS XML)
FROM    Table1
FOR     XML PATH('')
```

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side... You might add `,ROOT('root')` after the `FOR XML PATH('')` to get a valid XML back.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed! I knew there had to be something more elegant than dynamic SQL...

Answer (score 0):

By adding `FOR XML RAW` at the end of any query will produce XML close to what you are looking for. Also, you can specify element name by adding it at the end, such as `FOR XML RAW ('ELEMENT_PARENT')`, or a root name, `FOR XML RAW ('ELEMENT_PARENT'), ROOT ('Example')` .

As for as dynamic elements (or attributes before they are XML-ized) and error catching, you can employ any of standard bag of tricks offered by sql.

FWIW, I found this site that walks through several different examples with increasing complexity on ways to output XML data from a SQL script.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/

Comment: Why should I prefer FOR XML PATH() ?